# Parse Query String with HTTPclient to extract nameValuePairs

Tags: java, apache, url, tomcat, decoding

Is there Apache utility that takes Query String and some encoding and return Map of key,value[] url decoded?

Comment: Are you having some sort of encoding problem with values retrieved via HttpServletRequest's getParameter method?

Comment: @Powerlord maybe he isn't on a servlet environment.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel [tag:tomcat] is in the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's deprecated, but you can use [HttpUtils.parseQueryString](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpUtils.html#parseQueryString(java.lang.String)).

It maps parameter names to values. If the parameter appears more than once, the value is an array.

EDIT: The above method is deprecated because it doesn't allow you to specify character encoding.

The HttpClient project at apache has the classes you need to achieve this.

Use [URIUtil.decode(String data, String encoding)](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to decode the query string.

Then [ParameterParser.parse(String query, char separator)](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/ParameterParser.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20char)) to get a list of [NameValuePair](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NameValuePair.html)s. You can then put these into a Commons Collections [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), keyed by parameter name. (You could use a regular hash map, but that involves more code to handle multiple values per key.)

Comment: what about http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/util/RequestUtil.html#parseParameters%28Map,%20byte,%20String%29?

Comment: But, I didn't my app to depend on tomcat libs, Is it exposed else where?

Comment: My original suggestion doesn't use tomcat libs. It uses HttpClient and Commons Collections, both apache libraries.

Comment: The 1st link is also deprecated now.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a 4.x version of HttpClient, you will want to use `URLEncodedUtils.parse()`. It takes a URI (or string + charset) and returns a List of NameValuePairs.